# Issue Webscraping Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am brand new to Python - please and thanks in advance for your patience.

I have a site of customer reviews where I want to pull out the number of stars out of 5 that a reviewer gave a provider

In the below example, the reviewer has given the provider 1 star out of 5.  I want to be able to pull the "1" from the  below

```
<div class="rvw__hdr">   <div class="rvw__hdr-stat" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope="" itemprop="reviewRating">
    <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">   <img data-rating="1.0" src="//media.consumeraffairs.com/static/img/icons/stars/stars-1.a9f9f49815b7.svg" alt="Rated with 1 star" class="stars-rtg stars-rtg--sm">   <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="1">   <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">   </div> </div>
```

I have spent hours on this.
The nearest I have is the following:

```
rating = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="rvw__hdr-stat"]')

num_page_items = len(rating)
for i in range(num_page_items):
    print (rating[i].text)
```

This returns emptiness
when I omit the.text, I get objects returned for each of the 30 reviews on the page, one of which is as follows:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="271fc297-c03f-42b2-a680-2b5dd5656227", element="e1066956-81f4-4203-a2ae-5d3cdd95789a")>
```

I am clueless as to how to turn this into what I want, the actual rating number provided by the reviewer

I have tried other variations of driver.find_elements_by_.... with no luck

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This missing code is:

Comment: <div class="rvw__hdr">
  <div class="rvw__hdr-stat" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope="" itemprop="reviewRating">
    <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
 <img data-rating="1.0" src="//media.consumeraffairs.com/static/img/icons/stars/stars-1.a9f9f49815b7.svg" alt="Rated with 1 star" class="stars-rtg stars-rtg--sm">
 <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="1">
 <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Apparently the elements contained in `rating ` do not have a text. Could you share the page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: Yes, this is the URL:  https://www.consumeraffairs.com/insurance/unum.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get overall rating, you can get it from the attribute of div tag

```
overall_rating = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.stars-rtg")
print(overall_rating.get_attribute("data-rating"))
```

To get all consumer review ratings on first page, you can get it from the attribute of the img tag.

```
ratings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img.stars-rtg")
ratings_value = [rating.get_attribute("data-rating") for rating in ratings]
print(ratings_value)
```

Comment: Thank you Navarasu!!  That's exactly what I wanted!